# How to update adaptive card on task module on submit bot framework?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I have a requirement where I need to update as existing adaptive card on submitting a form from task module in Microsoft teams. I am able to achieve this by sending a new card but I need to achieve this by reusing the adaptive card which was sent as the main message.

The flow is as follows:-

1. Adaptive card with an update button is sent using the bot framework.
2. On pressing update, `handleTeamsTaskModuleFetch` is called inside my bot application. Here I make an api call to my backend to get the adaptive card for my modal. This is an input form.
3. On submitting the form, `handleTeamsTaskModuleSubmit` is called inside my bot application. Here I make an api to my backend to save the information. Post this I need to update my original adaptive card message, by adding a success/failure text.

The issue which I am facing is that I need the information about the existing card which was originally sent and update that. The documentation has shown ways to update by sending entirely a new card. I cannot use that because my card is dynamic and cannot have a fixed structure.

So my question here is that is there any way in which I can get the adaptive card that is sent in my main message, inside my `handleTeamsTaskModuleSubmit` function so that I can edit that and use `updateActivity` with `replyToId` to update the original message.

Comment: Could please refer below sample:-https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/54.teams-task-module
hope it's helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have already tried the sample out. It sends a new card on update. I need to get the existing card and add a success message to that.

Comment: When you send the initial card, do you get an activity instance back right after you send it? I can't recall as it's been a while since I sent a card in a task module...

Answer (score 1):

You can update the existing card using below code:

```
      var updateCardActivity = new Activity(ActivityTypes.Message)
                    {
                        Id = turnContext.Activity.ReplyToId,
                        Conversation = turnContext.Activity.Conversation,
                        Attachments = new List<Attachment> { Your Adaptive Card },
                    };
                    await turnContext.UpdateActivityAsync(updateCardActivity, cancellationToken);
```

Reference sample code link:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-faqplusplus-app/blob/master/Source/Microsoft.Teams.Apps.FAQPlusPlus/Bots/FaqPlusPlusBot.cs

Comment: I went over the code and in this case it is composing a new card from the payload, but not re-using the existing card sent. To give more context, I do not have the original card info at the time i submit the form and since its dynamic I cannot keep a single format and use that. I need to modify the existing card by adding a success failure block to it.

Comment: @Harkirat Saluja-Please have a look at this doc-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/universal-actions-for-adaptive-cards/work-with-universal-actions-for-adaptive-cards#refresh-model
Let us know if you have any query.

Comment: I went above the document shared, but its just a more generic way to send a **new** card. I need to get the **existing** card which is already sent and update that.

Comment: To update existing card on a button selection, pass a new Activity object with updated card and ReplyToId as activity ID to the UpdateActivityAsync method of the TurnContext class. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/update-and-delete-bot-messages?tabs=dotnet#update-cards

Comment: This is not possible as per the microsoft team. PFB the details here https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/6474